# Group ranges of numbers of a certain variable

Tags: r, dplyr, range, recode

I want to group the values of a certain column in my data frame.

Cluster 1: 1 to 249

Cluster 2: 250 to 1499

Cluster 3: >= 1500

Let's say I have a data frame containing 2 Variables (V1, V2):

```
V1 <- c(1,5,25,100,200, 1000, 10000)
V2 <- c(1,2,3,2,5,9, 4)
DF <- data.frame(V1, V2)
```

which will result in:

```
     V1 V2
1     1  1
2     5  2
3    25  3
4   100  2
5   200  5
6  1000  9
7 10000  4
```

so far I tried:

```
DF %>% mutate(V1=recode(V1, `200`= 1))
```

which indeed recodes 200 to 1 (for Cluster 1), but I do not know how to apply this on a range of numbers (1 to 249, 250 to 1499 and everything equal and above 1500).

Simply putting the numbers between a colon operator like:

```
DF %>% mutate(V1=recode(V1, `1:249`= 1))
```

returns an error:

> Warning message:
> Problem with `mutate()` column `V1`.
> ℹ `V1 = recode(V1,` 1:249 `= 1)`.
> ℹ NAs introduced by coercion

Is there a way to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: `DF %>% mutate(new = cut(V1, breaks = c(0, 249, 1499,  Inf), labels = c(1, 2, 3))` should do the trick

Comment: Another more explicit way to do it would be to use case_when 
df_grouped <- DF %>%
  mutate(cluster=case_when(
    V1 %>% between(1,249) ~ 1,
    V1 %>% between(250,1499) ~ 2,
    V1 >=1500 ~ 3,
  ))

Comment: Or: `DF %>%  mutate(V3 = case_when(V1 <= 249 ~ 1, V1 <= 1499 ~ 2, V1 >= 1500 ~ 3))`